# iMac freezes on a white screen when trying to start 64-bit install from a live DVD

Tags: boot, upgrade, 64-bit, mac, white-screen

The quarantine has got me trying new things, so I am a total noob here. Construction is much more my game.

I have an old (circa 2009) [iMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac#Timeline_of_iMac_and_Macintosh_models) with the [Intel T7600 Core 2 Duo CPU at 2.33 GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/27257/intel-core-2-duo-processor-t7600-4m-cache-2-33-ghz-667-mhz-fsb.html). I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it, and in my pride removed the old OS X. (I have since successfully updated to 18.04 LTS 32 bit). Without understanding anything, I installed 32 bit architecture but now need 64 bit to run the school programs my kids need.

My research has led me to needing to do a fresh install of Ubuntu to get to 64 bit architecture. I have confirmed that my processor will run 64 bit by running the 'lscpu' command in terminal and getting this feedback:

[lscpu screenshot confirms 64-bit capability w/ Intel T7600 2.33GHz CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYXCh.png)

I created a boot DVD for 18.04 LTS 64-bit but when I boot my computer with the dvd in the drive, it stops at a white screen. I can hear the dvd drive spinning but it locks here and won't go any farther. I thought maybe my disc was bad, so I made another. No luck. I tried my original 16.04 LTS dvd that I originally did my install with. No luck. I tried making a 16.04 LTS 64 bit dvd. No luck.

How can I get my computer to get to the boot menu so that I can make the change to 64 bit architecture?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: UPDATE: By pressing the 'Alt' key on my keyboard (using a Logitec wireless PC keyboard) during power-up, I was able to get to the boot menu where you can select which medium to boot from. However, now I am getting stuck at a black screen that says:
"1.
2.
Select CD-ROM Boot Type:"
At this point my keyboard becomes completely unresponsive. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With much help I found out that older Macs can run 64 bit but require 32 bit EFI. We found a 64 bit .iso with the 32 bit EFI and the install ran perfectly. The .iso can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mp1c2cf3f2dw25u/blackmacbook64.iso?dl=0